# Regex for validating xsd:ID string in Python?

Tags: python, regex, xsd

Would someone please suggest a regex for validating strings that are supposed to conform to xsd:ID ([link](http://www.schemacentral.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_ID.html)).

- The type xsd:ID is used for an attribute that uniquely identifies an element in an XML document.
- An xsd:ID value must be an xsd:NCName.
  **This means that it must start with a letter or underscore, and can only contain letters, digits, underscores, hyphens, and periods.**
- xsd:ID carries several additional constraints:

  - Their values must be unique within an XML instance, regardless of the attribute's name or its element name.
  - A complex type cannot include more than one attribute of type xsd:ID, or any type derived
    from xsd:ID.
  - xsd:ID attributes cannot have default or fixed values specified.

---

I am thinking of something like:

```
reg=re.compile('^([a-zA-Z]|_)(\d|_|-|\.)*')  
reg.match(mystring)
```

Does this look right?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest you can do is use two character classes, the latter with a `*` multiplier:

```
re.compile(r'^[a-zA-Z_][\w.-]*$')
```

`\w` already includes `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. There is no need to put groups around these, but you do want to anchor the expression to the start and end (`^` and `$`) to ensure you are validating the whole string, not just a portion of it.